# Enforce check constraint on uncommitted data

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014

*Note: I know a better practice for this example is to use a unique index, but this is just a simplified example of a more complex situation.*

I have a table with two values. And I have a check constraint to prevent duplicates of these two values:

```
Value1    Value2
------    ------
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
```

Given the above data, this should (and usually does) fail:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1,1)
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 15
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkTable1_DuplicateValues". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Table1".
>   The statement has been terminated.

However, in a race condition -- the case of two transactions trying to insert the same data at the same time -- the check constraint fails, and allows the data.

Here is how you can reproduce it:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Value1 INT, Value2 INT); 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION CheckDuplicateValues(@value1 INT, @value2 INT) RETURNS INT AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 
        WHERE Value1 = @value1 
          AND Value2 = @value2
    );
END; 
GO

ALTER TABLE Table1 
    ADD CONSTRAINT chkTable1_DuplicateValues 
    CHECK (dbo.CheckDuplicateValues(Value1, Value2) = 1);
GO
```

Then, in two separate windows (connections), run the following in both windows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1,1);
```

In both windows, you'll see:

> (1 row(s) affected)

I understand why this is happening -- basically, the query in the `CheckDuplicateValues` function is reading committed data only, plus the newly inserted data on the current connection, so in both cases, it's only counting the newly inserted row from the current connection.

I'm just not sure the best way to fix it. Should I throw a `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint on my UDF query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

I'm also not sure why the check constraint isn't enforced once the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` happens for the second query.

Is there a better way to handle this? Again, I know for this specific case, a unique index is the best way, but my check constraint actually involves a second table, so I figured a check constraint is the safest way to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Your example will not work as you state. You started a transaction and then did an insert. This will cause an updlock on the table so the second connection must wait until the lock is released. If you add NOLOCK to your UDF you will introduce some very challenging and unreproducible bugs. You will at some point get 0 returned because of a page split and the row in question will get missed. This happens with NOLOCK.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your example will not work as you state."? I set this up locally, and it works just as I stated. Are there database-level settings that would cause it to behave differently?

Comment: UDFs in check constraints are best forgotten about for a number of reasons. Possibly you are running at snapshot isolation and hitting the issue described in "snapshot isolation threat to integrity". There are ways round that with a `readcommittedlock` hint but you still have other potential performance and semantic issues ahead of you.

Comment: For slightly more complex unique index variants it is often possible to write an indexed view with the desired semantics and have the unique index on that enforce the desired behaviour in a declarative,correct, and  more efficient manner.

Comment: UDFs as check constraints do have some issues. You may have snapshot isolation on your instance. "Straight out of the box" the second insert will wait on the first transaction to complete before it can do anything.

Comment: You assume that your DML statement is atomic with respect to observing transactions. This is a common yet false assumption. T-SQL has race conditions like any other programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example the behaviour that you describe will only be experienced when either the transaction isolation level is set to snapshot, or the read committed snapshot setting on the database is set to on.  If these options are not set, then the first insert will work and the second will be blocked until you commit the first, at which point the second insert will fail with a constraint violation as expected.

If snapshot isolation is required on your database for any reason you can modify your function in your check constraint to replicate the behavior that would be experianecd in read committed isolation level by use of the readcommittedlock table hint like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckDuplicateValues(@value1 INT, @value2 INT) RETURNS INT AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
        WHERE Value1 = @value1 
          AND Value2 = @value2
    );
END; 
GO
```